# copy root.disk to another computer and change grub.cfg

Tags: linux, boot, ubuntu-10.10, grub2

I installed ubuntu 10.10 on a new laptop and copied the old root.disk of ubuntu 10.10 from old laptop to this new laptop, and booted it so I had to make changes to the grub menu using "e".

That is change the uuid and `root=/dev/sda2` and the computer booted properly into the old ubuntu 10.10 but these changes are temporary... so I wanted to make the changes permanent I tried editing **grub.cfg** but after that the operating system doesn't boot...

If I try `gksudo gedit /boot/grub/menu.lst`    turns up blank

I want to know:

1. how to change the grub menu (grub.cfg)?
2. how to make changes to grub so that the changes are permanent?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question. I hope this helps someone who is doing the same thing as I am.

```
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```